# Программирование в Bash в среде Linux

Tags: linux, shell

Разработать программу вычисления:

- суммы
- среднего арифметического
- максимума
- минимума

последовательности чисел, вводимых с клавиатуры.

Количество чисел последовательности задается пользователем.

Результат выводится в файл.

Comment: @Luchik, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @Luchik для арифметических операций в bash используются двойные круглые скобки ((a=a+1)); и баш не поддерживает float, так-что среднее арифметическое получится только целым.

Comment: @eicto в таких примерах иногда испрльзуют bc или ещё чего

Comment: @alexlz bc это не bash :) так можно и perl использовать (хотя bc конечно считает точнее в базовом функционале )

Comment: Если допустить, что нужно все таки делать для вещественных чисел, но на чистом баше, то задача стает чуточку интереснее (хотя никто не мешает просто домножить числа на 1000000 и оперировать ими. А в конце просто вставить правильно точку).

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что в задании подразумевается использование для арифметики в .sh скрипте  awk или bc (или чего-то еще).

В этом больше практического смысла. А для упражнений в "чистом" программировании bash вряд ли можно признать хорошим языком.

Comment: помню, когда учился в институте и изучал программирование, то преподаватель, зная меня, всегда к моим задачам добавлял спецусловие, которое сильно усложняло жизнь (например - не использовать дополнительных массивов, использовать не более 20 байт памяти под свои переменные, сложность не более O(ln)).

Comment: @KoVadim, не сомневаюсь, что получая такую спецподготовку, Вы не бегали по форумам с *такой формулировкой* вопросов.

Comment: Тогда хешкода не было. и stackoverflow... Форумы были, но не настолько... Хотя это уже оффтопик.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

:>temp

echo "введите числа, по одному на строку"
echo "ввод чисел завершите пустой строкой"

while true; do
  read line
  if [ "$line" = "" ]; then
    break
  else
    echo "$line" >> temp
  fi
done

:>res

sed '$!s/$/+/' temp | xargs echo | bc | sed 's/^/сумма: /' >> res
strok=$(cat temp | wc -l)
sed '1s/^/(/;$!s/$/+/;$s/$/)\/'${strok}'/' temp | xargs echo | \
bc | sed 's/^/среднее арифметическое: /' >> res
sed '1{s/^/a=/;s/$/;/};1!{s/^/b=/;s/$/;if(a<b)a=b;/};$s/$/print a/' \
temp | xargs echo | bc | sed 's/^/максимум: /;s/$/\n/' >> res
sed '1{s/^/a=/;s/$/;/};1!{s/^/b=/;s/$/;if(a>b)a=b;/};$s/$/print a/' \
temp | xargs echo | bc | sed 's/^/минимум: /;s/$/\n/' >> res

cat res
```

пример выполнения:

```
$ bash zadacha 
введите числа, по одному на строку
ввод чисел завершите пустой строкой
1
2
6
0

сумма: 9
среднее арифметическое: 2.25000
максимум: 6
минимум: 0
```